# How can i change color of text of spinner?

Tags: android-spinner

I want to change the color of the default text in the spinner in dialog mode. If the text is "Select Gender" only its color change and others will be set as default. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You don't show anything you've tried and perhaps that's because you don't know whee to begin?

Have a read of this, [Beginners CSS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-started-with-css-in-5-minutes-e0804813fc3e/)

It will help you get started with styling elements in Html documents using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).